# Scrambling an image?

Tags: php, css, image, encryption

I find myself reading comics in a number of different ways. What always interests me is how the companies behind the comic viewers reduce piracy. For example comixology use flash. Not uncrackable of course but deters most.

Anyway I really bought some comics on google play for the first time and was really intrigued to find out how google would protect their comic images.

[image: google scramble]

[image: css]

It appears that they scramble the images and then reassemble them on the fly in the reader! Really cool ay?

I was hoping to actually recreate and implement a similar effect. I understand the basic principle behind and have drawn out how I could do this very roughly.

With a tool like ImageMagick I could crop the image in the equal chunks ([like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309761/divide-photo-to-x-and-y-pieces)) and then stitch them back together but I'm really unsure about the browser side. I image there's some sort of key or seed which is called when the page is loaded that determines where everything goes but I'm unsure how I'd implement this.

So my question is really how would you go about implementing something like this? With each image having a key or maybe locked by a master key. But also is there a particular name for this other than image scrambling? Or an existing library/system that does this sort of thing. I'd love to read into it more or maybe even see more examples of it

UPDATE:

I thought I'd give Image Magick a go based on the code in the link I provided above. I've managed to split the image into chunks but it just feels massively inefficient chopping up the images and create actually files. Ideally I'd like to instead store references to these cropped images and then drop then straight into a new image. Anyone every tried to do something similar with imagemagick? Load times are pretty high and it just feels like it could be a lot more efficient

Another UPDATE:

Been messing around with this code for a while and it's really starting to feel a bit impractical in terms of the time it'll take. Processing an image into chunks/tiles/whatever you want to call it takes can take upwards of a minute and that's after I've resized it to a more manageable size. I don't think PHP is the best option for this anymore... Alternatively I was thinking about making this process run in a desktop application and then simply uploading the complete file and an a key to reverse the process to the web server so all it'd be handling would be the displaying. I'm pretty handy with Python and C# so I could do it in one of those languages. Do you guys think this would yield significantly better performance? Or is this just an issue that I'm always going to encounter with this sort of thing?

Comment: Can you please explain how you implemented your above question or still you have not implemented in any programming lanaguage

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable to download image from canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230222/disable-to-download-image-from-canvas)

Answer (score 0):

The HTML appears to display the images in a simple table. Each image chunk goes in a TD. Your server-side code would need to output each image chunk in the correct TD, so it would need to know how you created the chunks in the first place. Maybe the name of each chunk includes its position ("row" & "column"). Maybe each image chunk file name is stored in a database, along with a value for "row" and a value for "column". Maybe each image chunk file name is sequential, alphabetically, and they're just displayed left to right, top to bottom, in that order. Seems like there are several fun ways to implement this! I'm interested to hear what you decide to use.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have an algorithm to scramble the array of image chunks, you'd need to reverse it to display them in the browser. In the browser, they're displaying one image over and over, with different offsets (the background-position) like a sprite sheet.

One way to get the algorithm would be to generate an array of random numbers (0 through number of chunks, without repeating), and align each chunk `x` at `array[x]`. For calculating the offsets, you'd have to search through the array for `array[x]` to find `x` and multiply it by the width of your chunks. I don't think there's any real reason to introduce multiple rows into the crypto'd image, but the process would be similar with height adjustments/wrapping for the number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

I programmed something like this in Visual Basic 6 time ago for a reveal the picture mini-game... but I used Bitblt graphical function that allowed me to make the chunks. I defined a two-dimensional array and assigned the chunks randomly on the tiles, and on each tile I stored the X and Y position that the chunk actually has in the non-scrambled image.

Answer (score 0):

ImageMagick will do the tiling very quickly and simply for you in one go:

```
convert -crop 64x64 in.jpg tile%d.jpg
```

which will chop up your image (`in.jpg`) into tiles of 64px by 64px and name them `tile1.jpg`, `tile2.jpg` etc.

On my iMac, I can chop up a 1000x12000 pixel image into 304 pieces in 0.18 seconds.

Comment: Tbh, I was running imagemagick on a low spec, throttled shared hosting box. I did yield better result on a VPS... The bigger issue which I never got around to solving was shuffling these tiles into a seeded random order and then reassembling them like the image in my original post. Should probably come back to it tbh...